# Pandas .dot returning all NaNs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I'm performing a dot product from the pandas package on two dataframes, one of shape (462,36) and the other (36,34). The operation returns all the right headers and the returned dataframe is of the right size, but has NaNs for all the values. Every value is an integer in the original dataframes, I'm not sure why this error is happening.

For example, the code that I'm running is:

```
 df_technique = pd.DataFrame(df_binary.dot(df_pim.values), columns=df_pim.columns, index=df_binary.index)
```

where df_technique is the desired dataframe, df_binary is the larger dataframe, and df_pim is the smaller one.

For example, df_binary looks like:

```
 Customer ID      Email      Bait #1      Bait #2      Bait #3    ...
 12345            i@me.com   1            0            1          
 ...
```

df_pim looks like:

```
 Bait Number      Technique #1       Technique #2        Technique #3      ...
 Bait #1          1                  0                   0
 ...
```

The expected output is:

```
 Customer ID      Email      Technique #1      Technique #2       Technique #3      ...
 12345            i@me.com   1                 3                  4
 ...
```

The shape of the resulting dataframe should be (462,34).

EDIT: The solution, thanks to @Wen, is:

```
 df_technique = pd.DataFrame(df_binary.values.dot(df_pim.values), columns=df_pim.columns, index=df_binary.index)
```

Comment: Show us your sample file ?

Comment: Your df shapes cannot be broadcast together, what is the expected final dimensions?

Comment: `np.dot(df_binary.values.dot(df_pim.values))`

Comment: Revised example and final dimensions in original question

Comment: @Wen That worked!!! Such a simple fix, not sure how I missed that!